# Showing Review Summary on Category Page

Tags: category, magento-1, review, product-review

I want to show **customer reviews** of product on **category page**.How can i do? *please help*

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to Magento SE, Do you need avg review rating on category page for every product? where you will show all reviews on category page?

Comment: i just want reviews to of product related that are in category and show there reviews on category page

Comment: well this is bit confusing, I mean where you will show all the reviews of all products on category page.

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/get-product-reviews-product-sku-magento-2/ 
check this link you will get all reviews of a product

Comment: can you please guide me how i create module for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this block in your category template :

```php
// .yourThemePath./templates/product/list.phtml
<div class="product details product-item-details">
    [...]
    // Reviews Stars
    <div class="product-list-rating-stars">
        <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the stars are showing and it looks fine from your part , do some css styling .